# Moshi - Upgrade Issue 1.8.0 to 1.12.0

Tags: android, kotlin, upgrade, moshi

I upgraded from moshi 1.8.0 to 1.12.0, everything is working fine in debug build and if we freshly install release build.
But if we upgrade from old app version to new version which having moshi->1.12.0, values are coming as null when using converters for data classes.
I'm using moshi saving & retrieving details to shared preference and Room database, so now I'm receiving null values from it.

**Notes::**
**Moshi:**
old version - 1.8.0
new version - 1.12.0
**Kotlin:**
old version - 1.3.72
new version - 1.5.21

Comment: Probably missing Proguard rules, check https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/moshi/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/moshi.pro

Comment: I'm using same proguard rules only